# How to implement multi-threads Java RMI with shell commands by python?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, shell

I used Java to implement a distributed algorithm `Birman-Schiper-Stephenson`. Every time I run this program, I need to open three terminals and type command `java Server 2`, `java Client 0 2`, `java Client 1 2` separately in three terminals to activate a server and two clients.

Now I want this process to be automatic and I try to use python to write a script to run those java files automatically. I tried the code as below:

```
import os
import thread

thread.start_new_thread(os.system('java Server 2'))
try:
    thread.start_new_thread(os.system('java Client 0 2'))
    thread.start_new_thread(os.system('java Client 1 2'))
except:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

However, there's something wrong with the multithreaded process. I have to terminate the `Server process` then the `Client process` can be activated.
Can anybody tell me how to implement this multiprocess with shell commands by python?

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` blocks, so each thread you spawn is going to block the parent thread until execution is done (which, in the case of your `java Server` call, probably means it will never exit).

A simple way to get around this is to use the `subprocess` module (which is recommended for executing stuff you'd use `os.system` for).

```
import subprocess

commands = [
    'java Server 2',
    'java Client 0 2',
    'java Client 1 2'
]

# using subprocess.Popen will run sub-processes in parallel
java_procs = [subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True) for command in commands]

# now wait for the processes to finish?
for p in java_procs: p.wait()
```

If you need more serious multiprocessing/parallel process execution, the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module is usually a better recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailed reply. I've tried this method and it reminds me `java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)` when I run the script for the second time. Does that mean I need to add something like `for p in java_procs : p.kill()`  to kill processes by myself?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit you probably should start the server, then the clients then wait for all the clients to exit via `wait`. Afterward, stop the server - If you want this server to start and stop with the Python script.